# Rotating a circle image shifts it's position

Tags: geometry, antialiasing, image-rotation

I am trying to rotate a circle image using jquery rotate plugin. But, I observe that the circle image appears to be oscillating about it's center while rotating. Something like a linear movement.

In IE7, it's pretty much observable. In Chrome/Firefox, if you zoom a bit, this wobbling issue can be observed.

I tried to rotate the image using Raphael library too. But still, the circle was wobbling.

Then I rotated the image with a c# program to see if the problem is with the browsers' graphic engine. But even here this issue is observed. I even took various images to see if the circle was imperfect. But, all the images show this behavior.

Can this be happening because of anti aliasing? Or, is it just an optical illusion?

If not, then what else can be the reason?

I am using jqueryrotate plugin rotate method to do this. `$('#circleimg').rotate(Position);`

Comment: Why don't you show us some code and some pictures?

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot add an image because I don't have enough reputation points. The image is a circle with just one line along the radius inorder to capture the position.

Comment: Try putting the image on imgur.com and including a link in your post, even in plaintext if needed.  Not sure how much rep you need to post an image, but here comes a few points. :-)

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot... I have uploaded the image in imagur:
 http://imgur.com/KgUDClr

I need 10 reputation points to upload it here.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this jsFiddle.  Btw, this is the kind of source code you can include ***yourself*** in your question to make answering it easier for others.

http://jsfiddle.net/KyJzQ/

I used [this](http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/files/jQueryRotateCompressed.2.2.js) rotate plugin since you did not specify which one you used.

**HTML**

```
<img id="circleimg" src="http://i.imgur.com/KgUDClr.png">
&nbsp;
<img id="circleimg2" src="http://i.imgur.com/sK4qP6z.png">
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var rot = 0;

window.setInterval(function() {
    $('#circleimg').rotate(rot);
    $('#circleimg2').rotate(rot);
    rot += 1;
    },
    5
);
```

I think the circle you've provided is not actually a perfect circle, hence the tiny "oscillations" you see.

I added another circle that I rendered myself.  If you zoom in closely enough you will see jagged pixels moving around the edge of my circle, but I don't see any way around this since the jQuery plugin is not actually re-rendering the image.  I don't see any of the "oscillating" you mention in my circle.

This issue is more about vector art than it is about programming.  Get a nice vector graphics program and render the nicest circle you can.  Even the one I made is not really that good.  Or use HTML5 and canvas to draw dynamically, rather than moving a static image around.

Comment: Thanks a lot..
I had mentioned already that I was using jQuery rotate plugin. Anyways, as you said, the problem is not with the library.
Anti aliasing was in fact causing the problem. I used the image by turning off anti aliasing with paint.net and the wobbling issue is no more there! Though, the circle looks gnawed off along the border

Comment: No problem.  And there is more than one "jQuery rotate plugin" which again is why I specified which one I used (guessing which one you used) with a link. :-)  I'm still not sure it's possible to do with a pre-rendered image since images are rendered for a vertical/horizontal grid on the monitor, which does not rotate along with the image.  If you are averse to using HTML canvas drawing, maybe you could rotate an image of the line only, overlaid on a circle which does not rotate?  Please consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem. :-)

Comment: Here is a fiddle of the approach I describe above.  (http://jsfiddle.net/TWb6N/1/)  No wobbling, no "gnawed off" look.  Of course, now it's not even 100% obvious the entire circle is moving... but that is a side effect of the border being rendered exactly the same at all angles. :-)

Comment: Hi The111, thanks a lot.
Unfortunately, this solution would not work for me, because, I another image to rotate and show above the circle. Since we are supporting IE7, we cannot do this, because iE7 does not support rotating overlapped images.
Anyways, I reduced the anti aliasing by and tweaked the border width. Now, it's looking better. :)  

http://jsfiddle.net/HariprasadKamath/h7SSz/